# Is there really such a thing as an irreversible process?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

If an isolated system goes from a state A to B, will it always eventually fluctuate back to state A? If not, give an simple example.   Is it right to say that entropy only says that the probability for reversal is very low, but not actually 0, ie that it will take a very long time for some processes to reverse themselves, but they will infact eventually happen with probability 100%?

So will the universe eventually fluctuate back into yesterdays state? Or do we add some other physical law to make it irreversible?

Answer (score 5):

Mathematical/formal answer:

In classical statistical mechanics the answer is "no return to the *exact* same state".  Although the Poincare recurrence theorem indicates that a given isolated system will return to a state that is arbitrarily close to a selected initial state, phase space is continuous and the probability of reaching any specific state is zero.

Answer (score 3):

No. Entropy ensures that not all (in fact, almost no) processes are reversible in reality. The classic example is an egg breaking. It can never go back to its initial state.